# java: bits, bytes and hex values

Tags: java, hex, byte, bit

I have 8 values:

```
speed1: 50
length1: 10

speed2: 30
length2: 5

speed3: 100
length3: 50

speed4: 50
length3: 1
```

I need to send these 8 values with the follwing command:

```
< send 0x001 8 XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX >
```

The "XX" are hex values.

Right now I'm confused how to do that.
Any suggestions?

Comment: make an effort, try your best, and come back when what you tried didn't work. show us the code and the error and then we'll help u

Comment: I tried the following:
- converting the values to bits
- converting the bits to bytes
- and then: no idea to get from bytes to hex values :(

Comment: show the code, show the errors, give details, and do it in the question

Comment: `bits` are Binary digITS. So try to convert them to hexadecimal values instead. Group eash 4 of them and create a hexadecimal digit

Answer (score 0):

I guess it was way too easy. Here is a simple solution:

```
intToHex(value)
```